# Adding a missing 'Restricted View' permission Level - which check-boxes to check

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-permission-level, restricted-access

I have 3 sites in Sharepoint for classes I have. In the site of one class I was able to successfully create a new group that would allow users to read but not download files with an available permission named 'Restricted View'. However, when I tried to replicate this in the other two sites for some reason the pre-populated permission level 'Restricted View' was missing. Therefore, I am now trying to add a new level in these other sites with the same name ('Restricted View') that behaves the same way. I am now looking at the lengthy list of check-boxes which should be chosen to mimic this permission level. I would like to ask if anyone knows which boxes must be checked for this permission level. The description of this level is:

**Restricted View** - Can view pages, list items, and documents. Documents can be viewed in the browser but not downloaded.

Comment: After tinkering around a bit, I saw some advice about a different out-of-the-box permission that essentially works the same called: "View Only - Can view pages, list items, and documents. Document types with server-side file handlers can be viewed in the browser but not downloaded." However, before I could see this permission, I needed to activate the site collection feature called "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features".I was then able to create a new group with the View Only permission.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, you should activate SharePoint Server Enterprise Site features、SharePoint Server Standard Site features and SharePoint Server Publishing in the site features and site collection features. Then you will see 'Restricted View' permission level in the site permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried 'Per my test, you should activate SharePoint Server Enterprise Site features、SharePoint Server Standard Site features and SharePoint Server Publishing in the site features and site collection features. Then you will see 'Restricted View' permission level in the site permissions' - All permission came up, but restricted view is not coming up.

Answer (score 0):

To make the 'restricted view' permission available for the library

1. Put any file into the document library
2. Disable inheritance for that file in SharePoint settings
3. Restricted View permission now available for library and can be assigned to user, domain group...etc.